# Script bash with issues with extended characters ASCII in name of folders

Tags: bash

I have a need to pass a script to a perl script to run in some directories in linux (ubuntu) with bash --version
GNU bash, versión 4.4.20(1)-release (x86_64-redhat-linux-gnu)

These directories have a problem, and that is that they have extended characters including spaces, and local language characters.

```
IFS=$'\n'
for dir in $(ls -1ld  /home/setdart/mail/setdart.com/albertit/{.,?}*/ | tr '\n' '\0' | xargs -0 -n 1 basename); do echo "$dir"; done > albertit.txt
```

Which gives me

```
.Archive
cur
.Drafts
.Junk
.My Folders
.My Folders.Clients
.My Folders.Cuentas
.My Folders.Enric
.My Folders.Google
.My Folders.Prove&AO8-dors
.My Folders.Prove&AO8-dors.Abdul
.My Folders.Prove&AO8-dors.Abdul.Dominis
.My Folders.Prove&AO8-dors.Datax
.My Folders.Prove&AO8-dors.DeepL
.My Folders.Prove&AO8-dors.Gerard Cuenca
.My Folders.Prove&AO8-dors.Lloguer iMacs
.My Folders.Prove&AO8-dors.Movistar - Mabel Serrano
.My Folders.Prove&AO8-dors.Vadim
.My Folders.Prove&AO8-dors.Xavi Navarro
.My Folders.Scott
.My Folders.Scott.20220224 Errores facturas pdf
.My Folders.Setdart
.My Folders.Setdart.Admin y Conta
.My Folders.Setdart.Admin y Conta.202203 Quotation errors
.My Folders.Setdart.Ident Clientes
.My Folders.Setdart.Log&AO0-stica
.My Folders.Setdart.Lotes entregados no pagados
.My Folders.Setdart.M Pal&AOg-s
.My Folders.Setdart.Madrid
.My Folders.Setdart.Ramon
.My Folders.Setdart.Tasaciones
.My Folders.Software
.My Folders.Spam etc
.My Folders.Tests
.My Folders.Tests.E-mails Setdart
.My Folders.Tests.Reclamaciones
.My Folders.Tests.Reclamaciones.V1
.My Folders.Tests.Reclamaciones.V2
.My Folders.Tests.Recuperar codi d'usuari i contrasenya
.My Folders.Tests.Recuperar codi d'usuari i contrasenya.V1
.My Folders.Tests.Recuperar codi d'usuari i contrasenya.V2
.My Folders.Todoist
.My Folders.TPV
.My Folders.Varis
.My Folders.Web
new
.Sent
.spam
tmp
.Trash
```

Files containing `&AO8`, `&AO0-` are not processed by the second command, they are actually extended characters of the language

```
for file in $(cat albertit.txt); do echo "$file"; tools/maildir-size-fix.pl -a -f -c -r $file; done
```

I can't find a solution and I have more than 100 users in whom I have to pass the script and all of them, being Catalan, use Catalan as the language to name their folders.

I don't know how to proceed to do it.

Answer (score 1):

- do not parse ls https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead
- `for i in $(..)` is an antipattern.  https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/001
- `for i in $(command); do echo $i` Just execute the command, why loop with echo. It already echoes.
- check your scripts with shellcheck !
- `| tr '\0' '\n' | xargs -0` does not add any security. Just `| xargs -d '\n'` then, newlines are going to hurt anyway.

I could see something along:

```
printf "%s\0" /home/setdart/mail/setdart.com/albertit/{.,?}*/ | xargs -0 basename -z -a > albertit.txt
```

Or I think just:

```
find /home/setdart/mail/setdart.com/albertit/ -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d -printf "%f\0" > albertit.txt
```

And then:

```
while IFS= read -r -d '' file; do
   echo "$file"
   tools/maildir-size-fix.pl -a -f -c -r "$file"
done < albertit.txt
```

But then just:

```
xargs -0 -n 1 tools/maildir-size-fix.pl -a -f -c -r < albertit.txt
```

Comment: after run `printf "%s\0" /home/setdart/mail/setdart.com/albertit/{.,?}*/ | xargs -0 basename -z -a > albertit.txt` names has same issue of extender charcaters `.My Folders.Prove&AO8-dors`

Comment: `has same issue` what is the issue? Doesn't names contain the characters?

Comment: `Files containing &AO8, &AO0-` Any change in problem with extended characters.

Comment: I do not understand. `&A08` are four characters `&` `A` `0` `8`. There are no extended characters, in the sense they are in ASCII. What is the problem? What about those files?

Comment: ??? `.My Folders.Setdart.Log&AO0-stica` is not `.My Folders.Setdart.Logística` Is a part of problem object of question

Comment: How are you _displaying_ the data and what are you displaing exactly? `is not` Does `stat .My Folders.Setdart.Logística` succeed? How is it related to the question? There are no transformation in the code - I suspect that what you use to _view_ the file content transforms the content. `í` is `í`, nothing will happen to it.

Answer (score 0):

*Generally*, the simple construct of

```
for dir in /home/setdart/mail/setdart.com/albertit/{.,?}*/
do tools/maildir-size-fix.pl -a -f -c -r "$dir"
done
```

really should work, even with odd characters.
Does it not? Did you quote it?

If it doesn't, what does it do?